# Link libcairo in qmake project

Tags: c++, linux, qt, embedded-linux, qmake

I have a qmake project, to which I need to link [libcairo](https://cairographics.org/download/) on ubuntu desktop.

I have downloaded library to the system using `sudo apt-get install libcairo2-dev`.

The command `sudo apt-get install libcairo2-dev` gives me the output -

`I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng12 -lcairo`

I'm able to compile a `main.cpp`  with

`cc main.cpp -o main -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng12 -lcairo`

program which includes cairo header as `#include <cairo.h>`

But I'm not able to compile the qmake project with the following qmake flag added to `.pro` file

`LIBS += -I/usr/include/cairo -I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I/usr/include/freetype2 -I/usr/include/libpng12 -lcairo`

And there is an additional requirement, I need to link this library on a custom tool chain as well (embedded linux, yocto package). Can somebody help me out with this?

How can I specify the include path with the cross compiler? How can I conditionally specify include path for desktop build as well as target build?(both uses different sdk's)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the following:

```
LIBS+= -lcairo

INCLUDEPATH+=/usr/include/cairo
INCLUDEPATH+=/usr/include/glib-2.0 
INCLUDEPATH+=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include
INCLUDEPATH+=/usr/include/pixman-1
INCLUDEPATH+=/usr/include/freetype2
INCLUDEPATH+=/usr/include/libpng12
```

For yocto recipe it should be simple, you just need to add the following line in the recipe:

```
DEPENDS = "cairo"
```

Comment: g++ -c -pipe -g -std=c++0x -Wall -W -fPIC -DQT_QML_DEBUG -I../cairoTest -I. -I-I/usr/include/cairo -I-I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I-I/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/glib-2.0/include -I-I/usr/include/pixman-1 -I-I/usr/include/freetype2 -I-I/usr/include/libpng12 -I/opt/Qt/5.5/gcc_64/mkspecs/linux-g++ -o

this is the compile compile flags its being generated

Comment: It is working with the above recent edits, can t=you please explain how is the current modification is different from batch INCLUDEPATH?

Comment: Also let me know, how will I specify this this include path with the cross compiler. How can I conditionally specify include path for desktop build as well as target build?

Comment: for INCLUDEPATH I had accidentally added -I, which is not needed that is the reason why it didnt work in first place. For the yocto recipe which cross compiles you just add the line "DEPENDS = "cairo"" and rest yocto should take care.

Comment: Will the include path would be different in target device? If it is different how would we can take care of it?